# HAProxy allow port for specific hostname value?

Tags: haproxy

Is there a way to set HAProxy to listen on a specific port only if the hostname **from the IP used** matches a certain criteria?

The distinctin is important: My server has multiple IPs, which match a domain (www1.xxxx.com, www2.xxxx.com, etc).

I want to open port YYYY only if the domain used to connect to HAProxy is [www.xxxx.com](http://www.xxxx.com). If testing via www1.xxxx.com, that port would be refused.

Note that HAProxy is used in TCP mode, not HTTP.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this?

```
listen port_3306
  bind :3306
  mode tcp
  acl my-ip src 216.58.204.78
  tcp-request content accept if my-ip
  server  my-test-comms localhost:3306 check
```

Attaching the [documentation link](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#4.2-tcp-request%20content), may be you can play around with those settings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to do what I want. I have one other question related to this: instead of the IP, is it possible to use the $HOSTNAME variable from the environment and append a string (like 'www' + $HOSTNAME)?

Comment: NP! You can try something like this if it is hostname based `acl my-domain hdr(host) -i subdomain.mydomain.io` replace the access control lists definition line with the above it should work or you can add many number of acls and use or/and logics.